# in oozei with spark java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I use CDH 6.3.2

hadoop is HA

I make a workflow with spark in hue

run this workflow I get a error

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:478)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.org$apache$spark$deploy$DependencyUtils$$resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$3.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$3.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:355)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:186)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:93)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.runActionMain(LauncherAM.java:410)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.access$300(LauncherAM.java:55)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$2.run(LauncherAM.java:223)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:217)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
```

in my hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>nameservice1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.nameservice1</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled.nameservice1</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>bigdser2:2181,bigdser3:2181,bigdser5:2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.nameservice1</name>
    <value>namenode337,namenode369</value>
  </property>
```

I can run workflow with hive in hue

and I can run spark-shell --jars hdfs://nameservice1/sparklib/*.jar

"hadoop fs -ls /user" works.

it just dose'nt work with oozie

so how can fix it.someone can helpe me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete exclude resources/hdfs-site.xml  resources/core-site.xml in jar

Answer (score 0):

my job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://nameservice1
jobTracker=bigdser3:8032
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=True　　
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/jztwk
security_enabled=True
```

my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app  name="Spark-example2" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="SparkOozieAction1"/>
    <action name="SparkOozieAction1">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>Spark Example1</name>
            <class>App</class>
            <jar>JztCloudAnalyse.jar</jar>
            <spark-opts>--jars hdfs://nameservice1/sparklib/*.jar  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</spark-opts>
            <arg>-r 10.3.87.31:7000,10.3.87.31:7001,10.3.87.32:7002,10.3.87.32:7003,10.3.87.36:7004,10.3.87.36:7005 -d 0 -k 22 -w http://10.3.87.49:8082/SendMsgApi.ashx -n JZTanalyse10_102 -h JZTanalyse -o jjj</arg>
           <file>/user/jztwk/JztCloudAnalyse.jar#JztCloudAnalyse.jar</file>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Run oozie manually   "menas without hue"

it is also get the same error

Answer (score 0):

i also have this issue, use oozie 5.2.1 and apache hadoop 2.10.1
this is caused by applicationmaster can't find hdfs-site.xml from classpath, when we use spark-submit it will add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath

oozie also add it into classpath like
$PWD:$PWD/*:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:......

but i find the environment variable 'HADOOP_CONF_DIR' oozie submit to rm is empty

check below code, it set  HADOOP_CONF_DIR  to HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR

```
 private void setHadoopConfDirIfEmpty(Map<String, String> env) {
    String envHadoopConfDir = env.get(HADOOP_CONF_DIR);
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(envHadoopConfDir)) {
        String hadoopClientConfDirVariable = String.format("${%s}",HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR);
        LOG.debug("Setting {0} environment variable to {1}.", HADOOP_CONF_DIR, hadoopClientConfDirVariable);
        env.put(HADOOP_CONF_DIR, hadoopClientConfDirVariable);
    }
    else {
        LOG.debug( "Environment variable {0} is already set to {1}.", HADOOP_CONF_DIR, envHadoopConfDir);
    }
}
```

eventhrough i add env 'HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR' which the same value with HADOOP_CONF_DIR, i find the issue still not resolved, i have no idea, then i just find another way to specify the environment variable,

add follow configuratition in core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.10.1/etc/hadoop/</value>
</property>
```

Finally, i solve the issue this way